# How can I change background-position with arrow-keys?

Tags: javascript

Hi just started trying to learn a little javascript, now for my first programm I wanted to write code that moves the "background-position" when pressing arrow-keys.
So I hope one of you guys can help me to fix my code.

My (not so fancy) Code:

```
 var x = 0;
 var y = 0;

function GetChar (event){
        var keyCode = ('which' in event) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
        posy(move(keyCode, x, y))
        posx(move(keyCode, x, y))
    }


function move (key, x, y){
    if (key === 38){
        return y ++;
    } if else (key === 40){
        return y --;
    } if else (key === 39){
        return x ++;
    } if else (key === 37){
        return x --;
    } else{

    }
}

function posy(movy) {
    return body.style.background-position-y + movy * 100; 
}

function posx(movx) {
    return body.style.background-position-x + movx * 100; 
}
```

Comment: `var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;` (Also, the name `e` is quite common for the Event object; it's less characters.)

Comment: It's `else if` not `if else`

Comment: `document.body.style.backgroundPosition = movx*100 + 'px ' + movy*100 + 'px';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var posx = 0;
    var posy = 0;

    $(document).keydown(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode==40){
                posy--;
                console.log('down');
            }else if(e.keyCode==38){
                posy++;
                console.log('up');

            }else if(e.keyCode==39){
                posx--;
                console.log('right');

            }else if(e.keyCode==37){
                posx++;
                console.log('left');

            }else{

            };
        console.log(posy);
        console.log(posx);
        $('body').css('background-position-y', ''+posy*100+'px');
        $('body').css('background-position-x', ''+posx*100+'px');
    });
});
```